# ITMS-90339: Deprecated Info.plist Key

Tags: codenameone

I sent a new build of an app to App Store Connect and received the following warning :

**ITMS-90339: Deprecated Info.plist Key** - The Info.plist contains a key 'UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend' in bundle xxx that will soon be unsupported. Remove the key, rebuild your app and resubmit.

I was still able to continue with publishing the new version but this warning got me worried.

Comment: Even after removing the key UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend from Info.plist, I am still getting this error. It says the key is still available. Can you please let me know if i am missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in yesterdays update so if you send a new build that plist entry will no longer be there.

Answer (score 0):

My app was removed from sales so not available on App Store. I made the app available and everything is good